# 'Databinding complete' event for Silverlight 4.0 DataGrid?

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a DataGrid that I have bound to a property:

```
<cd:DataGrid 
    Name="myDataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=Thingies}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
...
```

When the `Thingies` property changes, *once all rows in the DataGrid have been populated with the new contents of* `Thingies`, I want the DataGrid to scroll to the bottom row.

In WinForms, I would have done this by subscribing to the DataBindingComplete event.  MSDN Forums contains several suggestions on how to do this with Silverlight 4.0 but they range from completely evil to just plain fugly:

- start a 100ms timer on load, and scroll when it elapses
- count rows as they're added, and scroll to the bottom when the number of added rows equals the number of entities in the data source

Is there an idiomatic, elegant way of doing what I want in Silverlight 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not derive from `DataGrid` and simply create your own `ItemsSourceChanged` event?

```
       public class DataGridExtended : DataGrid
       {
            public delegate void ItemsSourceChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

            public event ItemsSourceChangedHandler ItemSourceChanged;

            public new System.Collections.IEnumerable ItemsSource
            {
                get { return base.ItemsSource; }
               set
               {
                   base.ItemsSource = value; 

                   EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
                   OnItemsSourceChanged(e);
               }
           }

           protected virtual void OnItemsSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
           {
               if (ItemSourceChanged != null)
                   ItemSourceChanged(this, e);
           }
       }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I need to know when the binding is complete - i.e. when as many of the bound items have been rendered in the grid as is possible.  It's likely that the ItemSourceChanged event will fire before the rendering is complete.

Comment: @Duncan Have you already made use of the LayoutUpdated event and noted when that fires? It may fire post the rendering of the ItemsSource changing which would provide the hook you need.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this while searching for a resolution to the same problem.  I was finding that when I attempted to scroll the selected item into view after filter and sort changes that I frequently received a run time error (index out of bounds).  I knew instinctively that this was because the grid was not populated at that particular moment.

Aaron's suggestion worked for me.  When the grid is defined, I add an event listener:

```
_TheGrid.LayoutUpdated += (sender, args) => TheGrid.ScrollIntoView(TheGrid.SelectedItem, TheGrid.CurrentColumn);
```

This solved my problem, and seems to silently exit when the parameters are null, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ScrollIntoView method for achieving this.

```
myDataGrid.ItemSource = Thingies;
myDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(MyObservableCollection[MyObservableCollection.Count - 1], myDataGrid.Columns[1]);
```

You don't need to have any special event for this.

Comment: Harish, my understanding is that setting ItemSource causes the binding to happen asynchronously.  That means that in the code sample you've provided, ScrollIntoView() may be called before the last object in the collection has been bound.  That's why I need an event to indicate that the binding is complete.

Comment: Try to put your data binding statement in a try catch statement. And outside that, have your statement to scroll to the last record.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nice way to do it, in xaml, is to have the binding `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true`, and then you can hook the `TargetUpdated` to any event of your choice.

```
<ThisControl BindedProperty="{Binding xxx, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}"
             TargetUpdated="BindingEndedHandler">
```

Comment: Seems to be for WPF, not silverlight?